# Hidden Youtube autoplay on click image

Tags: jquery, youtube

Need some help please,

I am making an unordered list with once an image once an embed iframe from youtube, 
when clicking on the image it replaces the image with the hidden `iframe` from above using the `.replace` and `.prev` function of jquery

I was wondering if after clicking on the image the youtube video could autoplay, when adding autoplay to the parameters of youtube itself, it starts on page load, even when being set to display none.

I am doing this with using only classes, because the list will get big and I don't want to add for every separate id some jquery. I am not sure if this is even possible by only using classes.

Could someone guide me a little.

this is what I came up so far:

javascript:

```
$('.coverimageforplayer').click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).prev('li.showme').show());
});
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="showme" style="display:none">
        <iframe width="480" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/TZMoS2QBc8U?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </li>
    <li class="coverimageforplayer">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="showme" style="display:none">
        <iframe class="iframer_1" width="480" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/TZMoS2QBc8U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </li>
    <li class="coverimageforplayer">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ditch the showme list item as this adds unnecerary html and makes your code too complex in the long run.

I've written a small fiddle to demonstrate a more elegant approach, stash the video url in a data attribute on the list image, then insert a iframe on click and voila!

Here's the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/TxbHx/1/**

**The html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>autoplays:</li>
    <li class="coverimageforplayer" data-videoSRC="//www.youtube.com/embed/TZMoS2QBc8U?autoplay=1">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>Does not autoplay:</li>
    <li class="coverimageforplayer" data-videoSRC="//www.youtube.com/embed/TZMoS2QBc8U?autoplay=0">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The javascript:**

```
$('.coverimageforplayer').on('click', function() {
    var element = $(this); // reuse variables for best practice. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool--net-22142
    var videoSRC = element.attr('data-videoSRC'); // Get the video URL from the data attribute
    var iframe = '<iframe width="480" height="360" src="'+videoSRC+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; // create the iframe string
    element.html(iframe); // insert the iframe
});
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this valuable help, and I will definitely dig deeper into using vars for returning selectors. Thank you so much